# Are linking/copula verbs only followed by Adjectives and Nouns?

Tags: syntax-trees, copula

The diagram is from a lesson given by someone on YT. My question is with regard to the Adv phrases that follow the linking/copula verb. My understanding is that only predicate adjectives or predicate nominatives can follow a linking verb - not **adverbial** phrases. Am I misunderstanding something? Is this tree incorrect ? or what have I misunderstood?

Also - is "under water" is a prepositional phrase - so does it fall under a predicate nominative or predicate adjective?

I think "misleading" is a predicate adjective - as the participle "misleading" functioning as an adjective.

[image]

Comment: In English? Or generally? Please tag appropriately. Also do you want to include the ***[null copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_copula)*** in the question? (-;

Comment: I suppose I intended to ask "In English" but glad I did not because I never knew how it applies to other languages.

Comment: There seem to be several mistakes in this diagram. I take it that RelC stands for relative clause, but "(the report) that..." is no relative clause.  "Is misleading":  Here "is" is no modal verb and "misleading" is no adverb.

Answer (score 7):

Nominals (nouns and pronouns), adjectives, prepositions, subordinators (subordinate conjunctions), and some adverbs can be predicative expressions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression. The notion that a predicative expression must be an adjective or noun is too narrow. While it is true that adjectives and nominals are widely acknowledged as functioning as predicative expressions, prepositions, subordinators, and some adverbs can clearly also be viewed as predicative expressions at times.

Thus in the example in the question, the preposition *under* is a predicative preposition, and the participle/adjective *misleading* is also a predicative expression. Here are some more examples:

```
 a. It is on the table.

 b. The game was after school got out.

 c. That is soon.
```

The preposition *on*, the subordinator *after* and the adverb *soon* are predicative expressions. Note that participles (present active and past passive) are predicative expressions too (in fact, they are the canonical type of predicatives), e.g.

```
 d. It is happening.

 e. It is done.
```

The present progressive participle *happening* and the past passive participle *done* are predicative expressions.

The following article provides a good overview of what predicates and predicative expressions can be interpreted as being: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28grammar%29. I think real insight about the nature of predicates comes with knowledge of predicate-argument structures. Modern theories of syntax and grammar draw a three-way distinction; they acknowledge predicates, the arguments of predicates, and the adjuncts on predicates. Consider the following example in this regard:

```
 f. The book is on the table.
```

If one views the two-word combination *is on* as the predicate, then this predicate takes the two arguments *the book* and *the table*. This approach to predicates requires, however, that one jettison the (in my view erroneous) stance that the predicate in such a sentence is the entire string *is on the table*. The traditional binary division of the clause into a subject NP and a predicate VP is not supported by emperical considerations.

I will conclude this answer with a mysterious aspect of predicative expressions. Some adverbs can be predicative expressions, such as *soon* in the example above. Other adverbs, however, cannot function as predicative expressions, in particular those ending in *-ly*, e.g.

```
 g. *It is happily.

 h. *That is necessarily.
```

Why adverbs ending in *-ly* cannot function as predicative expressions, but most all other word categories can, is mysterious to me.

Answer (score 2):

That is very language-specific and works well for English, but not for many other languages. E.g. Russian can have an adverbial phrase following a copula, and many languages (like German) don't distinguish between adjectives and adverbs, moreover, many languages (like most of the Altaic languages) have neither adjectives nor adverbs.

Comment: That's right. In English there are two main uses for _be_: (1) to mark non-verbal predicates (predicate adjectives and predicate nouns), and (2) to mark verbal constructions, like the Passive and the Progressive. The adjectives and nouns fall under (1), but there are a **lot** of other syntactic constructions that use _be_. And participles are not adjectives, though they can be used as attributive adjectives.

Comment: @Jlawler, I think all the uses of "be" you point to here are instances of the same one auxiliary verb. In other words, there is no real difference between auxiliary "be" and copula "be". Stated otherwise, copula "be" is an auxiliary, not a full verb. We know that it is an auxiliary because it licenses subject-auxiliary inversion and VP-ellipsis, just like the other auxiliaries do.

Comment: It's an auxiliary in both cases, true; in fact, _be_ is virtually always an auxiliary verb. However, it's not always followed by an adjective or a noun in case (2); that was the point. And I don't use the term "copula"; it's another holdover from medieval grammar. _Auxiliary_ does the job nicely, and "copula" indicates a "linking" metaphor that doesn't refer to syntactic constituents, but rather to more vaguely remembered grammar school catechism.

Comment: @Jlawler, agreed.

Comment: Words that can be a copula or an auxilary verb can vary greatly - ranging from 'paint' to 'raise':
`The the fence was painted red` - here 'painted' is a copula and 'red' a predicate.
`The moon rose red` - here 'rose' is a copula and 'red' a predicate.

Comment: There is a difference between auxiliary "be" and the other verbs you have just produced. Auxiliary "be" licenses subject-auxiliary inversion and VP-ellipsis, whereas verbs such as "appear", "seem", "paint", and "rise" do not. Verbs like "paint" and "rise" are predicates that can subcategorize for another predicate, whereas auxiliary "be" can in no way be construed as a predicate, but rather it is part of the matrix predicate.

Comment: Yes, Tim's right. These verbs are more complex and have quite different syntax, of several varieties. Lumping them all under "copula" seems wrong; it makes "copula" a wastebasket category. If it means anything, it ought to be defined clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a too short answer, but I guess the entire question can be answered in this way:

The original phrase assumes an omitted word:

> *the island is **[located]** under water*

Which forms a pretty nice predicate adjective, as you suggested.

Comment: That doesn't work. It fails with a simple example such as "He is in a hurry" --> "*He is [located] in a hurry".

Comment: @TimOsborne Sorry I missed your comment. English does not have single words for different states of an object, e.g. time, location, or other condition. Only "located" is there, but there's no such thing as "time'd" ("he is behind schedule") or "condition'ed" ("he is in trouble" or as in your example). Does it make sense?